Iteract with solana Phantom wallet using Python language
I want to implement a code on Python language for Solana Phantom wallet.
I want to find some good free APIs or SDKs for python programming language to interact with Phantom wallet.
Those operations must be done:

Getting my wallet balance;
Swapping a SOL token to another token using token contract addresses and regulating swapping fees;
Which libraries or SDKs will be helpful to implement those interactions?


Please ask more specific questions about Solana programming. Eg "how do I get the balance of my wallet with Python?" or "how do I swap tokens with Python?" Additionally it's unclear why you would want to use Phantom wallet, which is an end-user tool, to do these things.
